# Code a huge formula into VBA combining IF and Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I need to reduce a file I am developing and I know one good way is using VBA. Unfortunately I am not advanced in VBA yet and I am struggling in designing this.
I have a list price organized in three different streams, and I want to combine in one like below:

```
Stream       Site          Brand Code   Price
Mainstream   Boston        Brand 01     Formula
Midstream    New York      Brand 02
Midstream    Los Angeles   Brand 02
```

Currently I am using a formula that basically does the following:

```
=IF(AND(stream="mainstream",Site = "Boston"),vlookup(Brandcode,list 1, 2,0),IF(ANd(stream="midstream", Site = "Boston", vlookup(Brandcode,list 2, 2,0),...))
```

The formula actually works just fine, the problem is I am testing many other conditions than just this one and thus the file is becoming very heavy, so I wanted to create a VBA code to create either a function or a subroutine, but I am struggling to understand how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be achieved without using VBA by using named ranges instead. Looking at the formula, it's clear that your lookup range varies based on the combination of `stream` and `site`.

You can create a `Named Range` for each of these lookup ranges. To do so, highlight the range of cells that contains the first lookup group (let's say Midstream New York). Next, press CTRL + F3 to open up the `Name Manager`. Finally, give this group the name `MidstreamNewYork`. (Note: you cannot include spaces in the name).

Next, you can update your `Vlookup` function. You no longer have to include the `IF(AND...` component because your lookups will be dynamic. Let's say you're inputting a formula on Row 2, the formula would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A2&B2, " ", "")),2,FALSE)
```

Let's break down the formula. (1) C2 is just the brandcode (I assumed it was in column C.`(2) The`INDIRECT`function treats a`String`as a`Range`. We are passing in Cells`A2`and`B2`, which are "Midstream" and "New York", respectively. We use the`SUBSTITUTE`function to remove the spaces since they aren't allowed. So now, we are looking up a named range called`MidstreamNewYork` (sound familiar?). (3) The rest of the VLOOKUP is standard: lookup the second column, and only match exacts.

Give it a try and let me know if it meets your requirements.